# How to fix com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.1.0

Tags: java, maven-2, ojdbc, maven-dependency

How can I solve the Maven error ?

> Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.1.0

I tried to add another dependency `hibernate-entitymanager` but it does not work.

Comment: Please provide your `pom.xml`.

Comment: create a (free) account with Oracle website and add the oracle maven repository to your repositories list: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/introduction.htm#MAVEN8755

Comment: Refer to blog (https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) for more details. We don't have the 10.2 JDBC version on the Oracle Maven. It starts with 11.2.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc14 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use oracle dependency in your Pom file if you are running your application on server , You need to add jdbc jar file to any folder in your project , And define in your pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```